# If a class has only a single member function enabled via requires can it still be ambiguously overloaded?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

For example, is this code valid?

```
template <class T>
struct A {
  void f() 
    requires std::is_same_v<T, int>
  {
  }

  void f(int) 
    requires !std::is_same_v<T, int>
  {
  }
};

int main() {
  auto fptr = &A<int>::f;
  return 0;
}
```

It won't [compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xFBZIwKjptKAFFwF) with gcc, but it seems like it ought to work to me.

Comment: I think it's that there's still two functions declared, it's merely that only one is callable.

Comment: There has always been something about opening a code block at the end of a header...mystery code blocks uncovered on Mars!!!  My dog just told me that if code won't compile WHERE you want it to compile then it isn't valid.  I'm going to go get him a bowl of ice cream.  BBL

Comment: GCC 7.1 compiles `void (A<int>::*fptr1)() = &A<int>::f; void (A<int>::*fptr2)(int) = &A<int>::f;`. This doesn't make sense to me, suggests a bug (or missing feature at best) in GCC. It might cause the behaviour you're seeing too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a class has only a single member function enabled via `requires` is it still considered overloaded?

**Yes.**

> `[C++ Concepts TS: 13/1]:` When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said to be overloaded. By extension, **two declarations in the same scope that declare the same name but with different types or different associated constraints (14.10.2) are called overloaded declarations**. Only function and function template declarations can be overloaded; variable and type declarations cannot be overloaded.

Overload resolution selects between them:

> `[C++ Concepts TS: 13.3.2/1]:` From the set of candidate functions constructed for a given context (13.3.1), a set of viable functions is chosen, from which the best function will be selected by comparing argument conversion sequences and associated constraints for the best fit (13.3.3). **The selection of viable functions considers associated constraints, if any** (14.10.2), and relationships between arguments and function parameters other than the ranking of conversion sequences.

---

> For example, is this code valid?

**Yes!**

Although there are two overloads here, the one with unsatisfied constraints is removed from consideration when taking the address of `f`:

> `[C++ Concepts TS: 13.4/4]:` **Eliminate from the set of selected functions all those whose constraints are not satisfied** *[..]*

This would, therefore, appear to be a compiler bug.

<sub>*Version cited: [N4377](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf), dated 2015-02-09*</sub>

Comment: Why is there no way for overload resolution to take place? `A<int>::f(int)` is removed from the overload set due to substitution failure, so there only remains `A<int>::f()` in the set

Comment: Thanks, I reworded the question to make it clearer what I was after.

Comment: I put in a bug report [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80637) if anyone wants to track.

Answer (score -1):

If you attempt to remove auto type deduction from your code for the problem line, the compiler gives a more appropriate message:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:18:40: error: conversion from '<unresolved overloaded function 
 type>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void()>' requested
   std::function<void()> fptr = A<int>::f;
```

Attempting to resolve `A::f` has two possible options, how is the compiler to know that you didn't screw up and intend to call the other one.

Comment: Downvote not mine but, while this is all technically correct, it doesn't seem to answer the root question

Comment: Yeah, I kinda jumped the gun on that one. To me `<unresolved overloaded function type>` has the compiler answering the question that this is indeed an overloaded function. I like your answer better though +1

Comment: I think the OP is asking us to confirm that the compiler is right

Comment: ahh ok, I misunderstood the question